# Mysql binlogs exists, show binary logs is empty

Tags: mysql, replication, binlog

I am working on a replication setup and have turned on bin-logs. I have moved my mysql datadir to a new location as well as the binlog path

From my.cnf

```
datadir = /vol/data/mysql
log-bin=/vol/data/mysql/mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
```

When I start mysqld and check the status:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000315 |      106 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

When I check the contents of /vol/data/mysql, I can see a lot of bin logs, but specifically, I can see this file was just created:

```
mysql-bin.000313
mysql-bin.000314
mysql-bin.000315
mysql-bin.index
```

If I tail the index file:

```
$ sudo tail mysql-bin.index
/vol/data/mysql/mysql-bin.000313
/vol/data/mysql/mysql-bin.000314
/vol/data/mysql/mysql-bin.000315
```

In mysql, there are no binary logs at all.

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

This means that purging binary logs in mysql has no affect. I checked the permissions of the directory and files and all belong to mysql user and group. Why can't mysql see and/or purge those binary logs?

```
mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
ERROR 1373 (HY000): Target log not found in binlog index
```

Comment: If you run `FLUSH LOGS;` does it generate `mysql-bin.000316` ?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@LOG_BIN_INDEX;` return?  Is that the same path and name as the "mysql-bin.index" file you're examining?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks, I received an error with that query.
mysql> SELECT @@LOG_BIN_INDEX;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'LOG_BIN_INDEX'

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA yes it did generate 000316.

Comment: Apologies, [the `@@LOG_BIN_INDEX` global system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_index) wasn't introduced until MySQL 5.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to try something a little unorthodox

```
service mysql stop
```

Open `mysql-bin.index` in vi

Change the contents to this

```
./mysql-bin.000313
./mysql-bin.000314
./mysql-bin.000315
```

Save `mysql-bin.index`

```
service mysql start
```

Login to MySQL and run

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

This stunt worked a few times for me.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion here. The key here was that when I went to edit that file, the very first line was blank. All the files were listed starting on the second line. Removing that blank line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case there was an empty line in the beginning of the index file.
After removing the blank line it worked fine.