# Mysql Slave doesn't find binary log from slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I have to setup a MySQL slave on an other infrasctructure. It will become the Master once that other infrasctructure is ready.

Mysql 5.6.29
Slave A in old infrasctructure
Slave B in new one

I dumped the Slave A database by performing a `STOP SLAVE;`, `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` then the `mysqldump` and restarted the slave with  `START SLAVE`.
I've now a perfect dump of my slave A with the master binlog and its position.

I dumped the dump into the Slave B and setup the correct binlog and position for the replication.
Once started, the Slave B couldn't find the binlog. But they are all in the right `/var/lib/mysql` folder on the Slave A. When I say they are all there I mean I put them myself in the folder in fact, otherwise they are deleted (I don't know why).

I really don't understand what I'm missing here.

`log-slave-updates` is ON on the Slave A

Comment: The error message is `Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'` Is both Mysql but Slave A is on Debian and the other in AWS RDS MySQL. I cannot check the my.cnf of the AWS RDS. @RolandoMySQLDBA suggests something: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87002/mysql-binlogs-exists-show-binary-logs-is-empty

Comment: Do you intend to hook B to A (daisy-chain)?  Or B to the Master?

Comment: Master -> A -> B. When I can begin the migration, B will become Master. Old Master and A will be killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to daisy-chain.

1. Since the binlogs were removed, I copied `rsync` them each 30 seconds
2. Dump Slave A to Slave B
3. Stop MySQL server `service mysql stop`
4. Copy back the deleted binlogs on Slave A in the MySQL data folder
5. Add the binlogs file name in [mysql-bin].index
6. Start Slave A `service mysql start` and the replication
7. Start the replication on Slave B
8. Monitor with `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on A and B

Answer (score 1):

Master -> A -> B

`binlog` on A needs to be turned on.

B must use the binlogs from A, not from the Master.

So...

1. Turn on binlogging on A.
2. Stop replication from Master -> A.
3. Dump A
4. Load dump onto B
5. `CHANGE MASTER` to point B to A.
6. Start replication from Master -> A.  Things should flow all the way to B.

Comment: Except that the binlogs on A are not there anymore. Can I change the mysql-bin.index on A?

Comment: You can't hang a slave off of A without having binlogging turned on.  With A stopped, you can safely have an "empty" binlog and the index.  But "no" binlog sounds like disaster - especially if A does not write binlogs after step 6.

Comment: The backup is done during the night. And in the morning, the binlog file on A referred to in the dump file is not there anymore.

Comment: What is purging it?  Not MySQL in less than a day -- see `expire_logs_days`.  Or are you referring to the "relay" logs, which are not relevant.

Comment: There must be something but I don't find it! `expire_logs_days` is not set at all in the confi which means it's 0 (no delete).
There is a hole of 13 binlogs missing between today 8.30am and 9pm. Hopefuly I backup the binlogs on A...